# Add Class to parent div where contain input checkbox with value

Tags: jquery

I have following code

```
<div class="subjects-list">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subject" value="Math">
</div>

<div class="subject-list">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subject" value="Sports">
</div>
```

I have checkbox value. I want to add class"taken" to div with "subjects-list" class and input with the specified value. What if the perfect way to do this?

for example if value "Sports"

```
<div class="subjects-list">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subject" value="Math">
</div>

<div class="subject-list taken">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subject" value="Sports">
</div>
```

**Solution**

I run in on ready document:

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index,item){
       var subject = $(item).val();
       if(subject == 'Sports'){
            $(item).parent().addClass('taken');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$(".subject-list").addClass("taken")`???

Comment: Note in the duplicate that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468308/519413) is the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add class to parent to div when checked then do this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox']).on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') {
    $(this).parent().addClass('taken');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('taken');
  }
});
```

Or If you want to just add class by value

```
$('input[type=checkbox']).each(function(index, item) {
  var subject = $(item).val();
  if (subject == 'Sprots') {
    $(item).parent().addClass('taken');
  }
});
```