# Using only CSS to change the background color of the answer choosen

Tags: html, css

I want to **change the color of the answer when player click to answer box (to choose it) like the picture below.**
[image]

Here is my html code, the radio box is a child of label. I tried some commands such as:

.choices > input[type="radio"]:checked {background: yellow;}

but seemingly it's not true. And someone please tell me the differences when I **put unchecked="checked" into the radio-box line?**

Thank all of you so much!

```html
 <!-- ---question1--- -->
              <div class="quest">
                <h1>Question 1 of 10</h1>
                <h5>Question 1</h5>
                <div class="group">
                  
                  <label for="opt1" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="q1" value="o1" >Option 1<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt2" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="2" name="q1" value="o2" >Option 2<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt3" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="3" name="q1" value="o3" >Option 3<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt4" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="4" name="q1" value="o4" >Option 4<br>
                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- ---question2--- -->
              <div class="quest">
                <h1>Question 2 of 10</h1>
                <h5>Question 2</h5>
                <div class="group">
                  
                  <label for="opt1" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="5" name="q2" value="o1" unchecked="checked">Option 1<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt2" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="6" name="q2" value="o2" unchecked="checked">Option 2<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt3" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="7" name="q2" value="o3" unchecked="checked">Option 3<br>
                  </label>
                  <label for="opt4" class="choices">
                    <input type="radio" id="8" name="q2" value="o4" unchecked="checked">Option 4<br>
                  </label>

              </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: On reading this question, it occurred to me that since we have `:focus-within` there's definitely an argument for `:checked-within` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky with CSS only but not impossible. I changed a bit the HTML structure but IT WORKS.

The `unchecked` attribute doesn't exist, you should only use `<input type="radio" id="opt1" name="q1" value="o1">` and add `checked` for the selected state like in the example below.

```css
.choices {
  position: relative;
}
.choices > input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
}
.choices label {
  padding: 4px 32px;
  display: block;
}
.choices > input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="quest">
    <h1>Question 1 of 10</h1>
    <h5>Question 1</h5>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="choices">
            <input type="radio" id="opt1" name="q1" value="o1">
            <label for="opt1">Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choices">
            <input type="radio" id="opt2" name="q1" value="o2">
            <label for="opt2">Option 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choices">
            <input type="radio" id="opt3" name="q1" value="o3" checked>
            <label for="opt3">Option 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choices">
            <input type="radio" id="opt4" name="q1" value="o4">
            <label for="opt4">Option 4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some have already pointed out that checked + label is a possible solution. Here is the example, but somewhat shortened.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <!-- ---question1--- -->
<div class="quest">
  <h1>Question 1 of 10</h1>
  <h5>Question 1</h5>
  <div class="group">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="1" name="q1" value="o1">
      <label for="1"> Option 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="2" name="q1" value="o2">
      <label for="2"> Option 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your mark up and little bit CSS.
main css will be
`input[type="radio"]:checked+.choices {background: yellow;}`
instated of this

```
<label for="opt1" class="choices">
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="q2" value="o1" unchecked="checked">Option 1<br>
</label>
```

you need to write like this for all inputs,

```
<input type="radio" id="5" name="q2" value="o1" unchecked="checked">
<label for="opt1" class="choices">Option 1</label>
```

l don't know your second question but I think there is nothing to think about it.

Comment: Thanks but you can give it an up vote. After all i am the first who write the correct answer. By the way thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

### The `for` attribute of the `label` should be the same as the corresponding `input`'s `id`

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="q1" value="o1">
    <label for="5"> Option 1 </label>
</div>
```

### There's NO `unchecked` attribute in HTML for radio!

We only have `checked` attribute. See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#attr-checked) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700626/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-and-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-html5) for more info.

### Styling

Since you cannot select the parent element in CSS, you can  your write code in the format I mentioned above and style the label of the input.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Otherwise, you need to use js: [if checkbox checked add class to parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468156/if-checkbox-checked-add-class-to-parent-element)

Answer (score 0):

> **You Can handle it in JScript, If you go to CSS documentation the css code might not work on old browsers**:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element1 = elements[i];
    element1.addEventListener('click', function(element1){
       
      this.firstElementChild.className="selected"
     }, false);
  element1.addEventListener('focusout', function(element1){
       
      this.firstElementChild.className="area";
      this.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked=false;
     }, false);
}
```

```css
.answer{margin-top:30px;}
.selected{background:yellow;padding:10px;}
.area{
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.area:active{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
  
<body>
<div class="Question_box">
  1. Question is to pick one.
  </div>  
  </br>
  <div class="answer">
    <label class="area">
      <input type="radio" name="data" id="1" class="radio"/> Option 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <label class="area">
      <input type="radio" name="data" id="2" class="radio"/> Option 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <label class="area">
      <input type="radio" name="data" id="3" class="radio"/> Option 3
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <label class="area">
      <input type="radio" name="data"id="4" class="radio"/> Option 4
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```